# Jgrasp not showing output for c++

Tags: c++

----jGRASP exec: C:\others\prajwal\practice programs\practice programs.exe

----jGRASP wedge2 error: command "C:\others\prajwal\practice programs\practice programs.exe" does not exist.
 ----jGRASP: operation complete.

I am not able to execute the c++ program. Please help!.

Answer (score 0):

Does "C:\others\prajwal\practice programs\practice programs.exe" exist? Did compilation and/or linking fail?

Comment: Compilation and linking runs fine. I was not able to find exe though. But there is file with .gpj extension